# Two columns of HTML elements don't stack closely

Tags: html, css

I have two columns in my web app when the screen is large enough.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQPlF.png

The issue is the space between the first element to the left and the one below it is bothering me.

```
.thumnnail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
}
```

is the CSS of the little boxes. I am not sure how to get them to stack. more closely. Let me know if more details are required!

EDIT: HEere is the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hkLXZ/

Comment: set up a codepen or fiddle? This code snippet isn't enough to help unfortunately

Comment: Can you show more html to us so that we can see how you put the boxes together? Like @Phlume said, an image does not tell us enough information to help you out

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You must have margins set somewhere. Can you post more code. You probably have margin: 1em 1em; but you probably only need margin-right: 1em; and then on your first column you would do margin: 0 1em; so that it spaces enough from the first element to the edge and the next element.

Comment: yo @Cam and I just added a JSFiddle link = ) also cam I am about to try what you reocmmend. I only did half of it, didn't see other half till now!

Comment: The jsfiddle, dont use a @import, that is what the external resource is for. Also, there is not much to work with on that. Can you put more to help.

Comment: Your fiddle does not look at all like your image o_O... Help us, help you...

Comment: @cam sorry! and blurfus sorry....... I made a mistake! the  link has been fixed!

Comment: You should also add to your female class vertical-align:top; so that your columns align.

Comment: Your fiddle says floa. What is floa?

Answer (score 2):

This requires one of two things:

1. Use CSS columns (e.g. `.your-element { column-count: 3; }`), in which case your columns will not stack left to right, but top to bottom.
2. Use a JS layout engine like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/layout-modes.html), which offers a lot more control with regard to how elements are laid out, but requires JavaScript.

Comment: doesn't help in my specific situation! plus number of columns depends d: just updated with jsfiddle

Comment: This answer is helpful. Floated elements with different heights but the same width will *not* nest as nicely as you'd like. If you're looking for a layout like Pinterest, follow @coreyward's suggestion and use Masonry.

Comment: @user2783087 Yes, it does, but go ahead and keep looking for another solution if you'd like…not that it'll do you any good.